# Unable to truncate date date from timestamp

Tags: date, amazon-redshift

In my redshift table, I have a column that has timestamp stored as - '2019-09-03 00:00:00'. I want to extract just the date out of it.

Tried both to_date and trunc function

```
select col, min(date) from table group by col
```

Also tried

```
select col, trunc(min(date)) from table group by col
```

I am still getting proper timestamp and not just date part.

Answer (score 1):

In redshift truncating timestamp will always give you timestamp back, but it's not a big deal - you can still store it efficiently, filter using it, group by it etc. If you really want to store just the date then cast your timestamp object to date.

```
select '2019-09-03 01:13:11' str, str::timestamp as ts, date_trunc('day', ts), str::date as d

str                 ts                          date_trunc                  d
2019-09-03 01:13:11 2019-09-03 01:13:11.000000  2019-09-03 00:00:00.000000  2019-09-03
```